# Can one element of a tuple reference another?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, undefined-behavior

**Update:** See the full answer below. The short answer is no, not directly. You can create an indirect reference using `std::reference_wrapper` or accomplish the same effect more generally with pointers (but without the syntactic sugar and added safety of references).

I ask because tuples make a convenient variadic storage unit in C++11. In theory it sounds reasonable for one element of a tuple to hold a reference to another element in the same tuple. (Replace "reference" with "pointer" and it works in practice.) The devil is the details of constructing such a tuple. Consider the following example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  A() : val(42) { }
  int val;
};

class B
{
public:
  B(A &a) : _a(a) { }
  int val() { return _a.val; }

private:
  A &_a;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b(a);
  std::tuple<A, B> t1(a, b);
  a.val = 24;
  std::cout << std::get<0>(t1).val << "\n"; // 42
  std::cout << std::get<1>(t1).val() << "\n"; // 24

  return 0;
}
```

The second element in the tuple `t1` references the automatic variable `a` instead of the first element in `t1`. Is there any way to construct a tuple such that one element of the tuple could hold a reference to another element in the same tuple? I'm aware that you could sort of achieve this result by creating a tuple of references, like this:

```
int main()
{
  A a;
  B b(a);
  std::tuple<A &, B &> t2 = std::tie(a, b);
  a.val = 24;
  std::cout << std::get<0>(t2).val << "\n"; // 24
  std::cout << std::get<1>(t2).val() << "\n"; // 24

  return 0;
}
```

But for my purposes that's cheating, since the second element in `t2` is still ultimately referencing an object that lives outside of the tuple. The only way I can think of doing it compiles fine but may contain undefined behavior [Edited to reflect more concise example provided by Howard Hinnant]:

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<A, B> t3( A(), B(std::get<0>(t3)) ); // undefined behavior?
    std::get<0>(t3).val = 24;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t3).val << "\n";
    std::cout << std::get<1>(t3).val() << "\n"; // nasal demons?
}
```

Edit: Here is a minimal test program that returns with a non-zero exit status when compiled using g++ 4.7 with -O2 or higher. This suggests either undefined behavior or a bug in gcc.

```
#include <tuple>

class Level1
{
public:
  Level1() : _touched(false), _val(0) { }

  void touch()
  {
    _touched = true;
  }

  double feel()
  {
    if ( _touched )
    {
      _touched = false;
      _val = 42;
    }
    return _val;
  }

private:
  bool _touched;
  double _val;
};

class Level2
{
public:
  Level2(Level1 &level1) : _level1(level1) { }

  double feel()
  {
    return _level1.feel();
  }

private:
  int _spaceholder1;
  double _spaceholder2;
  Level1 &_level1;
};

class Level3
{
public:
  Level3(Level2 &level2) : _level2(level2) { }

  double feel()
  {
    return _level2.feel();
  }

private:
  Level2 &_level2;
};

int main()
{
  std::tuple<Level3, Level2, Level1> levels(
    Level3(std::get<1>(levels)),
    Level2(std::get<2>(levels)),
    Level1()
  );

  std::get<2>(levels).touch();

  return ! ( std::get<0>(levels).feel() > 0 );
}
```

Comment: @Drise : From the [C++11 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info): "*Please tag questions about C++11 with the C++ tag, along with the C++11 tag.*" :-]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int&, int> t(std::get<1>(t), 2);
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << '\n';
    std::get<1>(t) = 3;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t) << '\n';
}
```

**Update**

I just asked about this case on the CWG mailing list.  Mike Miller assures me that this **is** undefined behavior per 3.8p6 bullet 2:

> ... The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> ...
>
> - the glvalue is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or
>
> ...

It would be well defined behavior if `tuple` was an aggregate, but because `tuple` has a user-declared constructor, 3.8p6b2 applies.

However this works, and avoids UB:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    int dummy;
    std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int>, int> t(dummy, 2);
    std::get<0>(t) = std::get<1>(t);
    assert(std::get<0>(t) == 2);
    std::get<1>(t) = 3;
    assert(std::get<0>(t) == 3);
}
```

Comment: He already clearly indicates that it "works for him". He wants to know if it is UB or not. Your answer does not answer this query.

Comment: It is a more concise example of what I was trying to do, though. Thank you!

Comment: I can attest with some expertise that `std::get` will only alias a tuple member.  However I have failed to find a quote in the language half of the standard that confirms that doing so in the way I've described above is not UB.  However there are some pretty smart language lawyers lurking around here and maybe they can classify this with relevant quotes.  Section 12.1 is where I would expect to find this info ...

Comment: What happens if instead of `int` you want a reference to a class for an expensive or exclusive resource? Is there a way to make use of std::reference_wrapper without needing `int dummy;`?

Comment: I see two options: 1. Switch from reference_wrapper to pointer. 2. Accept the UB of the `int&` solution. I'm not aware of any implementation where the `int&` solution will fail you.  And it is possible (an issue is being opened), that the `int&` solution may become well-defined in the future (no guarantee of that of course). At the end of the day, the best solution of all is to code something, and then have regular unit tests against whatever solution you have. That way even undefined behavior can be acceptable if the tests are standing by to catch assumptions gone bad.

Comment: From the section of the standard you cited (thank you!) it is still not clear to me that this is UB. What is meant by "access"? We are not modifying the tuple member, only obtaining a reference to it for later use. Is std::get<>() implemented as a static function or a non-static member function of the tuple, and is this compiler specific? Anyhow, please see edit to question; I am no fan of demons flying out of noses, and it _does_ hapen.

Comment: You are not the only one who is questioning the meaning of "access".  However the Core Working Group Chairman strongly feels that your code exhibits undefined behavior, and your "Level" experiment with gcc seems to confirm that the authors of gcc believe so too.  gcc is infamous for doing whatever optimizations it feels like when it spots undefined behavior.  My understanding is that the core issue being opened on this is to question whether or not this should be turned into well-defined behavior.  Fwiw, clang currently runs your Level code as one would expect, on all optimization levels.

Comment: `std::get<>()` is a non-static, non-member function (namespace scope).  This is specified by C++11.  It returns a reference to the tuple element.

Comment: My 2¢ is that this should be well-defined behavior. Providing a pointer or reference to already-allocated memory is no great burden to the compiler but a tremendous benefit to the programmer. Actually doing something to that already-allocated but as yet uninitialized memory should remain undefined.

Comment: There _is_ a way to avoid creating a "dummy" object for use with std::reference_wrapper. That is, if you're willing to play devil's advocate. `template <typename T> T& nullref() { T *n = nullptr; return *n; }` Then: `std::tuple<int, int&> t(42, nullref<int>()); std::get<1>(t) = std::get<0>(t);` Although dereferencing an invalid pointer is UB, there's no way for the compiler to know that there isn't really an object of type T at address 0 after all, and so it can't optimize anything out. Nothing bad should happen at runtime because the invalid reference is never used to do anything.

Comment: @Howard: I feel that your suggestion to accept undefined behavior (as opposed to implementation-defined) as long as tests are in place is a very bad thing.  Undefined behavior doesn't have to be deterministic, and following your suggestion could lead to a lot of code shipping with race conditions (among other possible problems).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I appreciate your respect for UB. I agree that it should not be tolerated lightly. Indeed, that is why I offered an option to avoid it. That being said, this is an engineering discipline and evaluating tradeoffs is common. When considering relying on UB it is important to understand your compiler, and the hardware it is running on. It is also good to know that the C++ standard is targeting hardware that you may not care about. For example left shifting a negative is UB just in case you want to run on a UNIVAC 1100. I'm content to restrict myself to 2's compliment hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, it is well-defined behaviour to alias an object which does not yet exist. This is the same situation as you can find using `this` in the constructor initialization list, which is unfortunate but common and well-defined.

Comment: It is well defined behavior to *alias* (and only alias, not use) an object that is under construction, but in the code in question `std::get` is called with an argument that has not yet finished construction, and depending on the implementation of `get` and `tuple` you might be causing undefined behavior just there.

Comment: I don't believe there is any possible implementation of `std::get` which is not a simple alias operation.